# C - String arrays and functions

Tags: c, arrays, string

So I've been learning C and getting really confused on string arrays and pointers.
I am trying to pass in an array into buildArrays and populate it and use it back in main. When I print the array at the end of buildArrays it prints fine, but when I print it at the end of the main function, the index 0 string prints fine then the rest are off.

```
void buildArrays(char *fileName, char wordArray[][50], char gridArray[][50],int columnCounter, int rowCounter ) {

  FILE *dat2; // Create File objects for input and output file .
  dat2 = fopen(fileName, "r");

  char mystring[columnCounter * 3];
  int c, columnIndex = 0, rowIndex =0;
  while(fgets(mystring, (columnCounter * 3), dat2) != NULL) {

        // printf("Line: %s\n",mystring);
        // printf("rowIndex: %d - rowCounter: %d\n", rowIndex, rowCounter);
        // printf("...\n");

        if(rowIndex < rowCounter){
          strcpy(gridArray[rowIndex], mystring);
          //printf("GridArray: %s\n", gridArray[rowIndex]);
        }
      rowIndex++;
    }
     for(int b=0; b<rowCounter; b++)
   {
      printf("%s\n", gridArray[b]);
   }

}


int main(void)
{
  int rowCounter, columnCounter , wordCounter= 0;
  char fileName[100] = "data1";
  getArraySize(fileName, &columnCounter, &rowCounter, &wordCounter);
  printf("%d x %d", columnCounter, rowCounter);
  printf("Number of words: %d", wordCounter);
  printf("\n");

  char wordArray[wordCounter][columnCounter + 1];
  char gridArray[columnCounter][rowCounter * 2];

  buildArrays(fileName, wordArray, gridArray, columnCounter, rowCounter);

  for(int b=0; b<rowCounter; b++)
   {
      printf("%s\n", gridArray[b]);
   }



}
```

buildArrays print

```
S T E L B M T F E Y D E E P S R T C I A E E

N N E L I T R L B D E T A R E M U N E T Y L

N O I T A N I M I R C N I F L E S S E N T A

A U I D E W A R R A N T N U P R U S S E R P

P G S G E A L P A P B A N P S A S S N M E A

C O N S I T U T I O N D E E C W S O O H P D

S V W D E L A N E E J A M E S M A D I S O N

A E D E S N E G R J C U L T N O H L T I R A

A R C E R R T R E E S B O N E E I D N N P R

S N J U D I C I A L A S S E C O R P E U D I

S M R A R A E B W B E S S M E O A U V P E M

O E O I A I L N O U C D O D S S E N N I G R

L N I D G Y T R C O M P E N S A T I O N N D

D T O Z E H P Y N D R L E E A O H S C O I B

I T P S U E T G O L U Z M M R B E H P I R T

E O I E A R R S U U I B H A Y L L M S T F A

R I N R E E E F U T L V Q U A R T E R I N G

S I D B S R R D I Y E N I G M I A N A T I R

S Q I S E B S C N S P E E C H R O T A E Y N

D L C M I L I T I A F L R N C A T S S P S E

R U T E D Y L E B I L C O H M L E T E S Y Y

L S T R T E W Z L I O S A E N S A E I Y A L
```

main print

```
S T E L B M T F E Y D E E P S R T C I A E E

T Y L

S S E N T A

U P R U S S E R P

B A N P S A S S N M E A

T I O N D E E C W S O O H P D

E L A N E E J A M E S M A D I S O N

E D E S N E G R J C U L T N O H L T I R A


P R

P E U D I

E O A U V P E M

D O D S S E N N I G R

C O M P E N S A T I O N N D

H P Y N D R L E E A O H S C O I B

P S U E T G O L U Z M M R B E H P I R T


A

R I N G

I A N A T I R
```

Comment: Aside: the code would be more readable if instead of `if((rowIndex+1) <= rowCounter)` you have `if(rowIndex < rowCounter)`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback,

Comment: ... but please don't alter the code posted on the fly or comments won't make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of the arrays in `main` doesn't match what `buildArrays` expects. The second dimension in `main` is dynamic, and usually not `50`, but `buildArrays` always assumes it's `50`. That's why your results are screwy; `gridArray[b]` refers to a place in memory `b * rowCounter * 2` bytes past the first byte of `gridArray` in `main`, but it refers to memory `b * 50` bytes past the first byte in `buildArrays`.

You see it misbehave only on the second and subsequent values of `b` (because `b` of `0` will multiply to `0` all the time). But when `b` is `1`, `buildArrays` is filling in bytes 50-100 (although it actually leaves most of them as `NUL`s), while `main` is reading from byte `rowCounter * 2` until it hits a `NUL` byte. For `b` of `1`, I'm guessing it tried to look in a spot that began with a `NUL` (thus the lack of output), but eventually some `b * rowCounter * 2` wraps back into non-`NUL` text, skipping past the:

```
N N E L I T R L B D E T A R E M U N E
```

part of:

```
N N E L I T R L B D E T A R E M U N E T Y L
```

and only prints the final:

```
T Y L
```

before it sees a `NULL` and stops.

Point is, your second and subsequent dimensions of a multidimensional array matter; the first dimension doesn't (a function just receives it as a pointer anyway), but all subsequent dimensions must be known to determine how to interpret indexing of that pointer.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and excellent explanation. That worked when I changed the max_string size to be the same.

Answer (score 2):

```
void buildArrays(char *fileName, char wordArray[][50], char gridArray[][50],
    int columnCounter, int rowCounter ) {
```

...

```
char wordArray[wordCounter][columnCounter + 1];
char gridArray[columnCounter][rowCounter * 2];
```

Unless `columnCounter + 1` is guaranteed to be 50 and `rowCounter * 2` is also guaranteed to be 50, the two functions will have different understandings of the memory layouts of `wordArray` and `gridArray`. So one function will not be storing the strings where the other function expects to find them.